# Google Maps API vs Google Maps Site Autocomplete results specificity

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

1. So attempting to  return results using Google Maps API. I'm also using googlemaps.places.Autocomplete for the origin and destination boxes. Oddly, I'm seeing a difference between it and how it works on maps.google.com.

Example: through Google Maps API
origin: I start typing "McDonald's, Woodruff Rd, Greenville, SC 29607. after selecting it that is exactly what it puts into the route calculation.

through Google Maps site (maps.google.com),
origin: I start typing "McDonald's, Woodruff Rd, Greenville, SC 29607. after selecting it, however, Google is resolving it to a more specific address,  McDonald's, 1111 Woodruff Rd, Greenville, SC 29607.

Obviously then the Google Maps route is more accurate/precise. Why is this altering of the selected address not happening through Google Maps API? is it an additional api call I need to use?

screenshot reference: http://cl.ly/2n3P1220042v

2. Also, the route directions through the API seems to drop the establishment name, leaving just the address. Google Maps site keeps the establishment name. How do I keep it through using the API?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `place` object returned by the google.maps.places.Autocomplete service has a `formatted_address` property which contains the address you are looking for.

input: "McDonald's, Woodruff Rd, Greenville, SC 29607"

`formatted_address: "1111 Woodruff Rd, Greenville, SC 29607, United States"`